# how to handle statuscode in android studio?

Tags: android, android-volley, http-status-codes

I am using volley liabrary for the login. After entered wrong password progressDialog is keep running until I kill the app. And one toast message is displaying(System Generated) that unauthorized user 401 statusCode.
I dont understand how to handle this condition?

Comment: Is statusCode is custom from your API or you are using network statusCode ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

new Response.ErrorListener() {

```
@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

    Log.e("Volly Error", error.toString());
    // Dismiss progress dialog here

    NetworkResponse networkResponse = error.networkResponse;
    if (networkResponse != null && networkResponse.statusCode == 401) {
        // Put your code here to handle this specific error code
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I tried this but progress dialog doesn't stop,it just keeps going

Comment: You need to dismiss progress dialog in onErrorResponse method as i have commented in above answer.

Comment: I did bt still its not working